# Using PBKDF2 SHA512 data in other languages

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, pbkdf2

I'm using `pbkdf2_sha512` as the hashing algorithm in a Flask web app.

I don't want to lose my user data in my database. Can I use the same hashing algorithm in the future if I want to change the backend programming language to any other language (like node.js, PHP, Ruby, etc)?

Will the same password hashing work for other programming languages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PBKDF2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) is a *standard*; in this case configured to use SHA512 as the hashing function. You'll find implementations for the standard in most programming languages. It is not unique to Flask or Python.

So yes, you can calculate the hash from any other language and test against the stored hash.

Example implementations in other languages:

- node.js: [`crypto.pbkdf2(password, salt, iterations, keylen, digest, callback)`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_pbkdf2_password_salt_iterations_keylen_digest_callback)
- PHP: [`string hash_pbkdf2 ( string $algo , string $password , string $salt , int $iterations [, int $length = 0 [, bool $raw_output = false ]] )`](http://php.net/hash-pbkdf2)
- Ruby: [`pbkdf2_hmac(pass, salt, iter, keylen, digest)`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/PKCS5.html#method-c-pbkdf2_hmac_sha1)

Comment: thanks a lot, #MartijnPieters , I will definitely try this.